# need to take out silver light installation on workstation using SCCM views

Tags: sql, sql-server

thanks for all support i get from this site.

i have query which i generally use to get percentage with modelcount.
iam using same to get silver light info on workstations, it is using SCCm cviews.

```
    select distinct(e.FileVersion0)  as version,count(distinct(s.Name0)) as modelcount, e.ExecutableName0,
(CAST((CAST(count(*) AS DECIMAL(18,2))/CAST((select count(*) from v_GS_INSTALLED_EXECUTABLE e inner join v_r_system s on s.resourceid=e.resourceid 
join v_FullCollectionMembership fcm on fcm.ResourceID = s.ResourceID where e.ExecutableName0 like 'Silverlight%')  AS 
DECIMAL(18,2))) *100 as DECIMAL(18,2))) as 'Percent', '%' as per
 from v_GS_INSTALLED_EXECUTABLE e
join v_r_system s on s.resourceid = e.ResourceID
join v_FullCollectionMembership fcm on fcm.ResourceID = s.ResourceID
where e.ExecutableName0 like 'Silverlight%'
and not e.ExecutableName0 like 'Silverlight.Configuration%'
group by e.fileversion0,e.ExecutableName0
```

iam using this query to get data like following

[image]

iam not getting percentages rights, iam not sure why because query for percentage iam using for other application like windows defender or SEP iam getting result.

```
    (CAST((CAST(count(*) AS DECIMAL(18,2))/CAST((select count(*) from v_GS_INSTALLED_EXECUTABLE e inner join v_r_system s on s.resourceid=e.resourceid 
join v_FullCollectionMembership fcm on fcm.ResourceID = s.ResourceID where e.ExecutableName0 like 'Silverlight%')  AS 
DECIMAL(18,2))) *100 as DECIMAL(18,2))) as 'Percent'
```

can you please help me out.

Comment: `DISTINCT` is **not a function** on a column, it's a part of `SELECT DISTINCT` and works on the whole selected rows. To make code clearer, skip those redundant parentheses and simply write `select distinct e.FileVersion0 as version, count(distinct s.Name0) as modelcount...`.

Comment: Besides you rarely never need to combine GROUP BY with SELECT DISTINCT, since the GROUP BY removes duplicates!